# Get max value by priority when specific column is not null

Tags: mysql, database

I have database table like

```
transactions
-----------
id
code
date
amount


formalities
-----------
id
transaction_id
```

this is query to get max value of transactions

```
SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM `transactions` n LEFT JOIN `formalities` r ON r.transaction_id = n.id
```

But what I want to achieve here is to get the max value of id group by transactions code, but the value must check if the transactions have relation to formalities or not.

If yes, get max value where they relate.
If not just get the usual max value.
Is there a query to achieve something like this?

example:

```
transactions
--------------------
id | code | amount |
1 | ABC | 10000 |
2 | ABC | 20000 |
3 | KOO | 10000 |
4 | ABC | 20000 |
5 | KOO | 30000 |
6 | KOO | 10000 |

formalities
-----------
id | transaction_id |
1 | 3 |
2 | 5 |
```

The result I want is getting the following output from the transactions table

```
id
-- 
4 
5 ( priority the one that have relation and get the max value)
```

Comment: I  really don't get your question the MAX(transaction_id)  makes no sense because o would expect a gruop by Code, Could  you explain your wish a little further

Comment: I want to get transaction id max value but transactions table not always have relation with formalities table. So what i want is like first priority getting max id of the one that have relation with formalities table

Comment: *transactions table not always have relation with formalities table* does your sample data include any rows without that relation? If yes which rows and why isn't there a relation? If no post sample data with rows that are not related. Clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN and get both - `MAX(transactions.id)` and `MAX(formalities.transaction_id)`:

```
select t.code, max(f.transaction_id), max(t.id)
from transactions t
left join formalities f on f.transaction_id = t.id
group by t.code
```

The result would be

```
| code | max(f.transaction_id) | max(t.id) |
| ---- | --------------------- | --------- |
| ABC  | NULL                  | 4         |
| KOO  | 5                     | 6         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgYfsDbtJgxWvcCBERyNPN/0)

To "prioritize" `transaction_id` column from `formalities` table you can use `COALESCE()`, which will return the first non NULL value:

```
select t.code, coalesce(max(f.transaction_id), max(t.id)) as max_transaction_id
from transactions t
left join formalities f on f.transaction_id = t.id
group by t.code
```

Result:

```
| code | max_transaction_id |
| ---- | ------------------ |
| ABC  | 4                  |
| KOO  | 5                  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rubGFSoENyXkJE5DrTUQGg/0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting the question right, but why don't you simply use -

```
SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM `transactions` n INNER JOIN `formalities` r ON r.transaction_id = n.id group by n.code
```

Comment: This is just getting max transaction id that have relation.

Comment: I want to get max transaction id that doesnt have relation too. But the priority is to get the one that have relation first

Comment: @KiraKatou: The example you have posted, gives the result of only those which match. Please provide with an explain, where the ids are not matching and you are getting the max result.